# Using ifelse function in R to sort results that fulfil a "less than and greater than"

Tags: r

I am trying to get this function to select outputs that fall in between two values.

```
Data <- Data %>%
  mutate(D= ifelse(A >= "80" & B == "InPlay" & (C <= "20")&(C >=  "6"), "YES", paste(D)))
```

So I would like column D to read "YES" when column A is greater than 20, column B reads "InPlay", and column C falls between 6 and 20.

Comment: A is greater than 20 or 80? also you need to remove the double quotes when you are comparing numbers

Comment: In R you can create new columns directly without `mutate`  `Data$D <- ifelse(...., "Yes", "No")`  Note than you can also create a logical column by returning `...TRUE, FALSE)`

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to compare the numbers as strings or as numbers?

If they are strings currently, Can you convert them to numbers using a = as.numeric(a)?
That'll allow you to use the typical operator functions.

The example below worked for me in a fresh script, I'm assuming you'd want this running inside a loop.

```
A = 90
B = "InPlay"
C = 15
D = "No"

if( A >= 80 & B == "InPlay" & C <= 20 & C >= 6) {
   D = "YES"
}
```